# ¿Como editar archivos en PowerShell?

Tags: windows, script, powershell

Expertos en **PowerShell** necesito de su apoyo.

Tengo en un archivo la siguiente información:

```
nombre_comando           valor                 
--------------           -----                 
systemctl                enable crond          
systemctl                disable avahi-daemon  
systemctl                disable dhcpd
```

Lo que quiero es editar el archivo anterior para escribirla en otro archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
systemctl = enable crond          
systemctl =  disable avahi-daemon  
systemctl = disable dhcpd
```

**¿se puede? toda la ayuda sera valorada  y agradecida** saludos les dejo mi intento aquí abajo pero no me funciona:

```
$argumento= "="
foreach($line in Get-Content .\procesos.txt) { 
  $array = $line.split(" ")
  foreach ($char in $array) {
    $char+$argumento >> archivo.txt
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```
$argumento= "="
$arrayRaw = Get-Content .\procesos.txt
$array = $arrayRaw[2..$arrayRaw.Count] -replace '\s\s+', ','
foreach($line in $array) { 
    $element = $line.split(",")
    $element[0] $argumento $element[1] >> archivo.txt
}
```

Comment: te lo agradezco mucho !!! me a sido de mucha utilidad

Comment: Me alegro mucho! Saludos